# Spring Boot - MongoDb find by manually created query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

In my application I'm creating manually some Queries and then I would like to simply find all entities which matches to the created queries. For that now I have to create a CustomXYRepository interface and implementation just to call the MongoOperations's find method. (example: this.mongoOperation.find(query, AppointmentDao.class);)
Again, my queries are constructed by the application itself, hence I would not use "static" @Query annotation and I would like to also avoid the custom repository implementations just for one single line. 
Is there any possibility to write a method like this in the Repository interface?

```
public interface CalendarRepository extends MongoRepository<AppointmentDao, String> {
...
    /**
       * Find appointments by the given query.
       * 
       * @param query
       * @return
       */
      List<AppointmentDao> findByQuery(Query query);
...
}
```

Thank you so much, have a nice day!

Comment: There is no way to achieve this. However, ideally, the query should be formed inside this custom method. Dealing with database objects (Query etc.) should not happen at multiple layers. However, it depends on your design.

Comment: You are right, the thing is (which is still not 100% correct) that because I would like to filter the data in many situations, each time differently I created a small framework which is able to build a query in the DAL. This is called EntityFilter and have multiple instances like: UserEntityFilter, etc. These filters are used in the BLL. The deep criteria building is hidden inside the entity but I still agree with you, that's not the best that I'm using an entity from the DAL in the BLL. (not perfect but it helps a lot) That filter has a method to build a query, that's why I asked the question